# Scala Stream prepend returns List instead of Stream

Tags: scala, scala-streams

I have a Seq, `x`, and a Stream, `y`, and I wish to prepend `x` to `y` to obtain a new Stream. However, the static type of `y` is causing the Stream to be evaluated immediately, and I am confused why this is the case. Here is an example:

```
val x: Seq[Int] = Seq(1, 2, 3)
val y: Seq[Int] = Stream(4, 5, 6)
val z = x ++: y // z has dynamic type List instead of Stream
```

Since the `++:` method is called on a Stream instance, I expect to get a Stream as a result, but instead I am getting a List as a result. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: Yeah, I know `Stream` is deprecated. But I need to use an older version of scala to be compatible with a library I'm using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tl;dr

it's because of compiler type inference, and when you are using `++:` on two `Seq` it's just construct another `Seq`. `++:` creates builder which return type param is `Seq`, but default `Seq` builder is `mutable.ListBuffer` and it's return type is `List[A]` which is also `Seq`. So, by default it  brakes **laziness** inside *builder* and return value will be `List[Int]` but return type will be `Seq[Int]`.

### Problem investigation

Lets watch to the `++:` signature (for example in scala 2.12.10):

```scala
def ++:[B >: A, That](that: TraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
    val b = bf(repr)
    if (that.isInstanceOf[IndexedSeqLike[_, _]]) b.sizeHint(this, that.size)
    b ++= that
    b ++= thisCollection
    b.result
  }
```

here we see implicit argument: `bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]`. In line:

```scala
val b = bf(repr) // b is Builder[B, That]
```

here `CanBuildFrom.apply` called, it returns `Builder[B, That]`:

```scala
trait CanBuildFrom[-From, -Elem, +To] {
  def apply(from: From): Builder[Elem, To]
}
```

When we call `++:` on two `Seq[Int]` we have default `CanBuildFrom` and `newBuilder` for sequences (from `scala.collection.Seq`):

```scala
object Seq extends SeqFactory[Seq] {
  /** $genericCanBuildFromInfo */
  implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, Seq[A]] = ReusableCBF.asInstanceOf[GenericCanBuildFrom[A]]

  def newBuilder[A]: Builder[A, Seq[A]] = immutable.Seq.newBuilder[A]
}
```

we see, that *newBuilder* calls `immutable.Seq.newBuilder` from `scala.collection.immutable.Seq`:

```scala
object Seq extends SeqFactory[Seq] {
  /** genericCanBuildFromInfo */
  implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, Seq[A]] = ReusableCBF.asInstanceOf[GenericCanBuildFrom[A]]
  def newBuilder[A]: Builder[A, Seq[A]] = new mutable.ListBuffer
}
```

We see `mutable.ListBuffer` which is not lazy.

### Decision

So, to keep laziness while your concatenation you should pass your own `CanBuildFrom` for `Stream[Int]`, something like that:

```scala
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable.Builder

val x: Seq[Int] = Seq(1, 2, 3)
val y: Seq[Int] = Stream(4, 5, 6)
implicit val cbf = new CanBuildFrom[Seq[Int], Int, Stream[Int]] {
  override def apply(from: Seq[Int]): Builder[Int, Stream[Int]] =
    new mutable.LazyBuilder[Int, Stream[Int]] {
      override def result() = from.toStream
    }

  override def apply(): mutable.Builder[Int, Stream[Int]] = Stream.newBuilder[Int]
}
val z = x ++:(y) // not it will be Stream(1, ?)
```

or you can just make streams from both sequences:

```scala
val x: Seq[Int] = Seq(1, 2, 3)
val y: Seq[Int] = Stream(4, 5, 6)
val z = x.toStream ++: y.toStream
```

and compiler will find implicit `CanBuildFrom` from `Stream` object, which is lazy:

```scala
implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, Stream[A]] = new StreamCanBuildFrom[A]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It seems I have been bit by an implicit.